# Accessing Google sheet view mode and extracting data using python

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

I am having a google sheet which is shared to me in view mode only, i wanted to extract the data from this view only google sheet using python.

I am able to extract data from google sheet which is in edit mode using below code, need to know if we can extract data from view mode google sheet as well?

```
import gspread 
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the issue of your script? By the way, in your script, it seems that you try to use the service account. For this situation, what is the file of `client_secret.json`?

Comment: This script works when access is given to google sheet . But I wanted to read and extract data from a view only google sheet

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. I had also asked `By the way, in your script, it seems that you try to use the service account. For this situation, what is the file of client_secret.json?`. If you cannot understand my English, please tell me.